# Uncaught type mismatch error: the type of an object was incompatible with the expected type of the parameter associated to the object

Tags: javascript

I'm running some javascript in Node Webkit and get the following error:

> uncaught type mismatch error: the type of an object was incompatible
>   with the expected type of the parameter associated to the object

I don't think it's Node webkit specific.... I think this is just a javascript error message that is hard to understand!

What does this mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my situation, I was passing the wrong type of object to a function.

For example, I was calling a function like so:

```
test(a,b,c);
```

For c, I was passing a string, when I should have been passing an array.

So this may pop up for you when your passing the wrong type of object to a function.

For example:

- you should be passing an array - you pass a string
- you should be passing an object - you pass an integer

Comment: i'm confused, is this an answer? or supposed to be an edit to the question?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I've edited it a bit, as it is supposed to sound like an answer ;-) It's basically a weird javascript error that I wasn't sure what it meant, and I hope to document what it actually means here! Thanks!

Comment: Well yes, it is. But in my opinion, in simpler terms that makes more sense. If it said "the type of an object was incompatible with the expected type of the parameter passed to the function", I may have got it straight off. But I didn't. I think my explanation is easier to understand than the error message above. I googled this error message and came up with nothing, so after awhile this will come up as a meaning for this error. Instead of spending 10 minutes trying to figure it out, someone will find it out in about 30 seconds ;-) Thanks!